# How can I use ctags with multiple Elm projects?

Tags: vim, elm, ctags

I use vim, and I'd like to be able to navigate to function and type definitions spread across multiple Elm projects. My understanding is that the easiest way to go about this is to use ctags.

There is an existing open [issue](https://github.com/ElmCast/elm-vim/issues/24) from January 2016 with various suggestions, including a link to [ctags-elm](https://github.com/kbsymanz/ctags-elm) which provides:

```
--langdef=Elm
--langmap=Elm:.elm
--regex-Elm=/^ *([[:lower:]][[:alnum:]_]+)[[:blank:]]*:[^:].*->.*/\1/f,function,functions/
--regex-Elm=/^ *([[:lower:]][[:alnum:]_]+)[[:blank:]]*:[^:][^-]+$/\1/c,constant,constants/
--regex-Elm=/^port +([[:lower:]][[:alnum:]_]+)[[:blank:]]*:[^:]/\1/p,port,ports/
--regex-Elm=/^type +([[:upper:]][[:alnum:]_]+)/\1/t,type,types/
--regex-Elm=/^type[[:blank:]]+alias[[:blank:]]+([[:upper:]][[:alnum:]_]+)/\1/a,type-alias,type-aliases/
```

If you install this in `~/.ctags`, you can scan all your sources:

```
$ ctags -R --languages=-all,+Elm
```

---

**However** this approach still has problems:

- It ignores qualified names, so an attempt to navigate to the definition of `List.map` will offer all the definitions of `Dict.map`, `Set.map`, `Random.map` etc.
- It scans all the `*.elm` files in all my directories, including tests and old dependencies.

Basically I'd like a solution that:

- Can follow qualified names☨ to their definition: navigating to `List.map` should prefer definitions of `map` in files named `List.elm`.
- Scans all the `*.elm` files in each project's `source-directories`
- Ignores everything in each project's `tests` directory
- Ignores all the built `*.js` files
- Optionally scans the **latest versions**☨ of library sources in each project's `elm-stuff/packages` directory

Is this possible with `ctags`, or with a ctags wrapper that parses each project's `elm-packages.json` file?

---

[☨] *Regarding qualified names:* I'm aware that some people abbreviate qualifiers, like:

```
import Math.Vector3 as V3
```

and I wouldn't expect a ctags regex to look for `V3.add` in `Math/Vector3`. 
The longer-term solution would be a tool that understands Elm modules and imports, like `hasktags` does for Haskell. For now I could live with ctags not understanding abbreviated qualifiers.

---

[☨] *Regarding latest versions:* Sources of dependencies are downloaded into `elm-stuff/packages/GITHUB-USERNAME/GITHUB-PROJECTNAME/VERSION-TAG`, and over time it is possible to accumulate multiple versions, eg:

```
elm-stuff/packages/kfish/elm-gamepad/3.0.0
elm-stuff/packages/kfish/elm-gamepad/3.1.0
elm-stuff/packages/kfish/elm-gamepad/3.2.0
elm-stuff/packages/kfish/elm-gamepad/3.4.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't answer on the Elm-specific points but…

> Ignores everything in each project's `tests` directory

Add this to `~/.ctags`:

```
--exclude=tests
```

> Ignores all the built `*.js` files

Add this to `~/.ctags` if they are not compiled in a specific directory:

```
--exclude=\*.js
```

or exclude the directory/directories in which they are compiled.

> Optionally scans the **latest versions** of library sources in each project's `elm-stuff/packages` directory

<strike>How do you define "latest"?</strike>

The only way I could think of to reach that goal would be to pre-compile the list of places to look in and feed it to `ctags` via the `-L` flag:

```
$ ctags -R -L list-of-files.txt .
```

Actually, writing a shell script to generate a proper `list-of-files.txt` could probably fix all your pain points. Maybe someone already thought about that…

See `$ man ctags`.

Comment: Thanks, and I've edited the question to clarify how versions of the dependencies are stored.